# Spring Boot 1.5.2 FreeMarker change from DEBUG mode to RETHROW mode

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker

How do I change the FreeMarker "DEBUG" mode to the "RETHROW" mode in Spring Boot 1.5.2. I'm getting the following message in my browser when an exception occurs:

```
FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!)
```

I've tried adding the following property to application.properties file:

```
spring.freemarker.template_exception_handler=rethrow
```

according to the following site: http://blog.64p.org/entry/2016/03/24/175906
but that didn't work.

Edit:

I saw there is a class called FreeMarkerProperties that has a class definition like the following:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.freemarker")
public class FreeMarkerProperties extends AbstractTemplateViewResolverProperties {
```

I assume this class should be filled with all the properties that starts with "spring.freemarker"

It has a method called getSettings. I decided to see what is returns if I autowire FreeMarkerProperties into my CommandLineRunner.

I changed my class that implements CommandLineRunner to the following:

```
@Component 
public class ApplicationLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger =     LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationLoader.class);

    ...

    @Autowired
    FreeMarkerProperties properties;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String option : strings) {
            sb.append(" ").append(option);
        }
        sb = sb.length() == 0 ? sb.append("No Options Specified") : sb;
        logger.info(String.format("WAR launched with following options: %s", sb.toString()));

        logger.info("FREEMARKER PROPERTIES");
        for(String path : properties.getTemplateLoaderPath()) {
            logger.info(path);
        }

        for(String setting : properties.getSettings().keySet()) {
            logger.info("Freemarker: " + setting);
        }
```

Which output the following:

```
2017-03-22 09:58:19.257  INFO 6635 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-03-22 09:58:19.292  INFO 6635 --- [           main] com.example.ApplicationLoader            : WAR launched with following options: No Options Specified
2017-03-22 09:58:19.292  INFO 6635 --- [           main] com.example.ApplicationLoader            : FREEMARKER PROPERTIES
2017-03-22 09:58:19.292  INFO 6635 --- [           main] com.example.ApplicationLoader            : classpath:/templates/
2017-03-22 09:58:19.852  INFO 6635 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 11.67 seconds (JVM running for 12.339)
```

So it seems like the FreemarkerProperties's getSettings method returns an empty list of settings. My application.properties:

```
# Spring Boot configuration.
# Uncomment below line to enable mobile device detection.
#spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.enabled: true
spring.metrics.export.delay-millis=10000
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/**COMMENTED OUT***
spring.datasource.username=*
spring.datasource.password=*
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
server.session.timeout=1800
spring.freemarker.template_exception_handler=rethrow
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Why is the settings not populated in the FreemarkerProperties class?

Comment: That would only work if you use spring boot auto config (if it would still apply) if you manually configured this it wo't work.

Comment: No I'm using auto config. When I go to the common properties webpage I don't see that setting (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). Does it mean I should configure it mannually then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your application.properties try using 
`spring.freemarker.settings.template_exception_handler=rethrow`

Comment: The valid values aside `rethrow` are `debug`, `html_debug` and `ignore`. They are defined in `freemarker.core.Configurable` https://github.com/apache/freemarker/blob/2.3-gae/src/main/java/freemarker/core/Configurable.java#L2672.

Answer (score 0):

In the Spring Boot Module of one of my apps I'm loading the Freemarker Properties file with a @PropertySource annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:/standalone.properties")
public class MailLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new
                AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.nixmash.blog.mail",
                "com.nixmash.blog.jpa");

        MailDemo demo = ctx.getBean(MailDemo.class);
        demo.init();
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) ctx).close();
    }

}
```

I'm not extending `AbstractTemplateViewResolverProperties` but rather using a config Bean

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerViewResolver freemarkerViewResolver() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("");
    resolver.setCache(false);
    resolver.setOrder(3);
    return resolver;
}
```

Here's the `.properties` file.

```
spring.freemarker.enabled=false
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/freemarker/
spring.freemarker.charset=UTF-8
spring.freemarker.cache=false
spring.freemarker.check-template-location=false
spring.freemarker.settings.locale=en_US
```

If your application includes multiple modules and `application.properties` files it could also be a matter of one module `.properties` file overriding your FreeMarker module `.properties` file. Renaming the FreeMarker module `.properties` file and using `@PropertySource` would expose the properties, in that case.