# How to catch freemarker TemplateException in ControllerAdvice spring boot?

Tags: spring, freemarker, exceptionhandler

Trying to figure out how to catch TemplateException in ControllerAdvice to have a possibility to log the exceptions.

Here is the configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class FreeMarkerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        resolver.setCache(true);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".ftlh");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates/");

        Properties settings = new Properties();
        settings.setProperty(freemarker.template.Configuration.TEMPLATE_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_KEY, "rethrow");
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);
        return freeMarkerConfigurer;
    }
}
```

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String handleException(final HttpServletRequest request, final Exception e) {
        String incidentId = logException(request, e);
        return "redirect:/error?incident-id=" + incidentId;
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(TemplateException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleTemplEx(Exception e,
                                         HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        logException(request, e);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

The CustomExceptionHandler doesn't catch TemplateExceptions, I'm just receiving an error in the console, something like:

> 18:16:39 | ERROR | http-nio-8080-exec-1 | freemarker.runtime    | Error executing FreeMarker template
> freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
> ==> articleTagIndice1s  [in template "themes/article.ftlh" at line 7, column 20]

Found a couple of similar topics, but none work for me:
[solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42919245/spring-boot-1-5-2-freemarker-change-from-debug-mode-to-rethrow-mode), [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426788/freemarker-template-error-handling-with-spring-mvc).

Comment: I'm not familiar with freemarker, but the controller advice will only catch exceptions that are thrown out of the controller methods.  It sounds as if that exception isn't being rethrown after the logging.  There's some pretty good information about freemarker error handling [here](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_errorhandling.html)

Comment: Thanks @lane.maxwell, the information provided by the article helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [the article](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_errorhandling.html) mentioned by @lane.maxwell I found the solution. Thus, the working configuration and the handler are below:

```
@Configuration
public class FreeMarkerConfig {
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() throws TemplateException, IOException {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates/");

    freemarker.template.Configuration configuration = freeMarkerConfigurer.createConfiguration();
    configuration.setTemplateExceptionHandler(new TemplateExceptionHandlerImpl());
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setConfiguration(configuration);

    return freeMarkerConfigurer;
}
```

TemplateExceptionHandlerImpl:

```
public class TemplateExceptionHandlerImpl implements TemplateExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ArticleCategoryIndexRestController.class);

    public void handleTemplateException(TemplateException te, Environment env, java.io.Writer out) throws TemplateException {
        try {
            String incidentId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            logger.error(String.format("=== INCIDENT ID %s ===", incidentId));
            logger.error("FREEMARKER TemplateException");
            logger.error("Template: " + env.getMainTemplate().getName());
            logger.error("Exception: ", te);
            out.write("<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">");
            out.write("Something went wrong, INCIDENT ID: " + incidentId);
            out.write("</div>");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new TemplateException("Something went wrong", env);
        }
    }
}
```